# adding an image to a UIView 's drawing without letting the image spread

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, paintcode

i have a UIView in which i am drawing a shirt using Paint Code. i have to apply an png image which will be the pattern of the shirt. The pattern when added spreads outside of the shirt. How to make the image not spread outside the shirt.

[the gray background is the UIView which is used to draw the shirt Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYaRs.png)

[the polka dot is the pattern which i want to apply to the image , how can i not make it spread?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MLQ1.png)

Comment: can you create your imageview of a bit smaller size compared to your shirt drawing?

Comment: @Ujjwal i have to add sleves too in the future view controller , i want the pattern to be shown on the sleeve too.

Comment: @AdityaYadav : What about Robert's answer?

Comment: If you need sleeves, then use a mask that has sleeves.

Comment: i solved it , by using the png file as an UIColor  with patternImage

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by replacing the colour of the view by adding the patternImage of the polka Dots.

`shirtView : UIColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "polka-dots.png")!)`